# What's the point of the Hoyle–Narlikar theory of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, modified-gravity

Many extensions of general relativity have been proposed, to solve various problems or expand it's range as a theorem. The one of these that caught my eye most recently is [Hoyle–Narlikar theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoyle%E2%80%93Narlikar_theory_of_gravity), a theory of gravity that reduces to GR in the limit of a smooth fluid model of particle distribution.

My question is simply, what's the goal of this theory? What holes is this theory trying to fill, or what questions is it trying to answer? It claims to give a theoretical backing to how matter is creating from nothing, but that seems to be an "auxiliary" part of the theory that is usually omitted because it does not agree with WMAP data.

EDIT: I mentioned this quickly with a professor who told me that, if correct, it gives boundary conditions on Einstien's field equations. What exactly does this  mean, and how does this theory accomplish it?

Comment: It's Hoyle so it's always for the bloody quasi-static universe

Comment: @Slereah And how does a quasi-static universe fill in any holes or solve any problems?

Comment: Hoyle was really opposed to the big bang cosmological model, hence he really stuck with the quasi-static model all the way.

Comment: @Slereah Are there any specific reasons a quasi-static model has advantages over a big bang model?

Comment: The big bang did not sit well with some scientists in the early days, due to seeming like a step back (back to Christian creation myths sort of thing), and not like the previous static universe model which was the consensus pre-general relativity. Some found it non-sensical to have the universe start off at a point in time.

Comment: Essentially, the advantage of the quasi-static model is that there is no "Why" left - you take the existence of the universe as a given.  With a point of origin, like the Big Bang, you are then left asking why the Big Bang happened.

Comment: @Adirian You're right! Thank you. Although of course the quasi-static model begs the question "why did the universe happen?"

Comment: @TreFox This isn't really physics any more, but in that model the universe did not 'happen': it has always existed.